# General Quesiton about where to mount a RAID VD volume, etc

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mount, automount, removable-storage

We recently re-installed UBUNTU on a system that had UBUNTU system on a 500 GB RAID VD (1 slot) and DATA on another RAID VD (5 slots, RAID 5).  After booting up the new system the RAID VD automatically mounted on /media, rather than on /mnt, which is where it was apparently setup before.  Just wondering if there is a particular convention for that because we might end up installing a new system on the system disk periodically, or restoring from a system disk image.

I don't think it makes much difference as to where things are located since the DATA volume has some Docker Containers and DATA that are pretty much self-contained and recovered just fine after installing the new system.

The RAID isn't exactly "removable" media, but sort of, and I guess the system treats it as such.

Comment: You have full control where filesystems are mounted. Use /etc/fstab. Regarding the best mountpoint, in my opinion it doesn't matter, but you may want to consult the [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Mount it where you need it.

Comment: What about ?  /srv     Really a user preference thing, but the DATA is mostly a Docker Folder with .yml and DATA, pretty much a virtual machine recipe with NGINX - PHP - Web Directories, Data files.  Interesting that the Server automatically mounted it on /media.  It is a PERC RAID card VD.

Comment: You could say the RAID volume is removable because the drives are hot swapable ?